# Ошибка при выполнении скрипта: NameError: name 'R' is not defined

Tags: python, ооп, модули

[image: Скрипт к модулю module]

Разделил программу на две части. Первая модуль, а вторая скрипт ( на скриншоте ). До разделения программа работала нормально, но при выполнении скрипта происходит ошибка в методе getNumRul класса Room:  NameError: name 'R' is not defined. 
 Не знаю как исправить неполадку, прошу помочь.

Скрипт:

```
    '''импортирование модуля с основной частью программы'''
from module import*

'''создание объекта класса Room'''
R=Room()
R.setRoom()

'''создание объекта класса WD (W - Window, D - Door)'''
wd=WD()
wd.setWD()

'''создание объекта обоев'''
Ob=Oboi()
Ob.setOboi()

'''вывод площади комнаты без учена окон и дверей'''
print('Square of room:',R.getSqr())

'''вывод площади комнаты с учетом окон и дверей'''
print('New square of room: ',R.getNewSqr())

'''вывод числа рулонов, необхлодимых для оклейкм всей комнаты'''
R.getNumRul()
```

Модуль:

```
class Room:

    def __init__(self, l=None, w=None, h=None):
        '''установка параметров объекта: l - длина, w -ширина , h - высота'''
        self.l=l
        self.w=w
        self.h=h

    def setRoom(self):
        '''интерфейс для установки параметров объекта'''
        self.l=int(input('etner lenght'))
        self.w=int(input('etner wigth'))
        self.h=int(input('etner height'))

    def getSqr(self):
        '''получение площади комнаты без учета пола и потолка'''
        return 2*self.h*(self.w+self.l)

    def getNewSqr(self):
        '''получение новой площади комнаты с учетом окон и дверей'''
        return Room.getSqr(self)-WD.sqrCount

    def getNumRul(self):
        '''получение числа рулонов оболев для оклейки комнаты новой площади'''
        return print('You need ',R.getNewSqr()/Ob.getSqrOboi(),' rulonov of oboi')

class WD:

    sqrCount=0
    '''счетчик суммарной площади окон и дверей'''

    def __init__(self,NumOfWD=None,lwd=None,hwd=None):
        '''NumOfWD - число окон и дверей вместе, lwd - длина окна\двери, hwd - высота окна\двери'''
        self.NumOfWD=NumOfWD
        self.lwd=lwd
        self.hwd=hwd

    def setWD(self):
        '''создание окон\дверей, нахождение площади, которую они вместе занимают.'''
        self.NumOfWD=int(input('etner NumOfWD'))
        for i in range (self.NumOfWD):
            self.lwd = int(input('etner lenght of WD'))
            self.hwd = int(input('etner height of WD'))
            WD.sqrCount+=self.lwd*self.hwd

    def getSqrWD(self):
        '''получение площади, занятой окнами\дверями'''
        return WD.sqrCount

class Oboi:

    def __init__(self,lo=None,ho=None):
        '''lo - длина обоев, ho - высота обоев'''
        self.lo=lo
        self.ho=ho

    def setOboi(self):
        '''установка параметров обоев'''
        self.lo=int(input('etner lenght of oboi'))
        self.ho=int(input('etner height of oboi'))

    def getSqrOboi(self):
        '''получение площади одного рулона обоев'''
        return self.lo*self.ho
```

Comment: `R.getNewSqr()` что такое R?

Comment: @ПавелДурманов, объект класса Room, Ob - объект класса Oboi.

Comment: И где они определены?

Comment: @ПавелДурманов, созданы в скрипте. Я так понимаю, что из-за того, что они созданы отдельно от основной части, метод getNumRul не может найти объект R и поэтому выходит ошибка.

Comment: `return print ` нужен или print или return, вместе они не работают.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в этом коде:

```
def getNumRul(self):
    '''получение числа рулонов оболев для оклейки комнаты новой площади'''
    return print('You need ',R.getNewSqr()/Ob.getSqrOboi(),' rulonov of oboi')
```

Это метод класса `Room`, и он ничего не знает об экземпляре этого класса, объявленном в другом модуле. Также он не знает и о переменной `Ob`. Если `R` можно заменить на `self`, то создание объекта `Oboi` придется вносить в этот метод (или вообще избавиться от объекта, превратить его в функцию).

Ну и `return` тут совершенно не нужен.

Comment: Ясно. Не могли бы вы подсказать, как создать такую функцию? Лично я решил сделать так: 

    `def setOb():
         Ob=Oboi()
         Ob.setOboi()`
    
 А в скрипте просто вызвать эту функцию, но попытка оказалась неудачной, та же ошибка, только на этот раз для Ob: NameError: name 'Ob' is not defined

Comment: @VyQwe для начала я бы посоветовал для тренировки вообще переписать без классов, просто через функции. Причем функции по максимуму в математическом смысле - в них что-то попадает, и они что-то возвращают, без ввода/вывода. По поводу класса дверей - не очень понятно, почему дверь должна знать общую площадь всех существующих в программе дверей. А если вам две комнаты обсчитать нужно будет? Площадь дверей (проемов) в самих комнатах должна храниться.

Comment: Вообще для данной задачи в принципе достаточно одного класса - класса комнаты: площадь проемов - это свойство комнаты, площадь обоев - это тоже свойство комнаты, это не отдельные объекты.

Comment: Ля, с функция ми бы сначала разобраться еще. А можно использовать статические методы ( @staticmethod )?

Comment: С функциями как раз проще. Вам желательно начать с чисто процедурного стиля (желательно без использования глобальных переменных), а потом переходить к ООП.

Comment: Ладно, спасибо. Попробую следовать вашему совету.

Comment: @VyQwe, чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа можно [принять ответ как правильный](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/348814)